# R: read in data

Tags: r

I tried to read in data into R. 
The original data in R looks like this(2 columns):

```
0001694304038 0001307304135
53693819142794292671008449081562285178 35902638881091172349429496704016716029
0001694315761 0002347472709
```

However, everytime I read this into RStudio, the data becomes

```
                  V1           V2
1       1.694304e+09 1.307304e+09
2       5.369382e+37 3.590264e+37
3       1.694316e+09 2.347473e+09
```

How can I make R read in the data like what they are in the original data ? (I would them to appear in RStudio in the form that I have in my original data file)

To elaborate, Column 1 and 2 are IP addresses and I am trying to obtain an igraph. It will make my life easy if I can keep the IP address as it is in the original data.

Comment: Can you read them in as strings, instead of integers?

Comment: How can you make R read them in as strings ? What is the command for it? I always use "import dataset" to import data into Rstudio. Never really worked with commands when importing data files into R

Comment: @Chinegro have a look at the help for `read.table`; there's a comprehensive list of options for reading in different kinds of structured data.

Answer (score 2):

Read your data file as strings, not integers. This will depend on which input method you are using. Using, e.g., `read.table`, you can set `colClasses` as follows:

```
dat = read.table(file="file.dat", header=F, colClasses=c("character", "character"))
```

Comment: I just read an article, saying that "scan" is better than read.table when working with large matrix. So if I were to use scan, what is the correct command ?

Comment: From http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/base/html/scan.html, you could use something like `dat = scan(file="file.dat", what=character)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `colClasses` argument.

```
read.table(*, colClasses=c("character", "character"))
```